# Gem is installed but not loading

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have installed the `api_auth` with `gem install api_auth`

but when I try to run a file that `require api_auth`, it tells me it's missing :

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- active_support/dependencies (LoadError)
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/api_auth-0.0.2.4/lib/api_auth.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `require'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `rescue in require'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in `require'
from /Users/thomasbentkowski/Documents/misc/apisandbox.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.4/lib/pry/pry_class.rb:91:in `block in load_requires'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.4/lib/pry/pry_class.rb:90:in `each'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.4/lib/pry/pry_class.rb:90:in `load_requires'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.4/lib/pry/pry_class.rb:128:in `initial_session_setup'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.4/lib/pry/cli.rb:206:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.4/lib/pry/cli.rb:83:in `call'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.4/lib/pry/cli.rb:83:in `block in parse_options'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.4/lib/pry/cli.rb:83:in `each'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.4/lib/pry/cli.rb:83:in `parse_options'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.4/bin/pry:16:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/bin/pry:23:in `load'
from /usr/local/bin/pry:23:in `<main>'
```

Here's the result of `gem environment`

```
- RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.0.14.1
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.0.0 (2015-12-16 patchlevel 648) [universal.x86_64-darwin16]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - universal-darwin-16
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0
     - /Users/thomasbentkowski/.gem/ruby/2.0.0
     - /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`api_auth` is intended to be used in Rails. It looks like you're loading a ruby script with pry. You will need to `require 'active_support'` wherever you are using `api_auth`